# Can you name this UI Component?

Tags: image

I wound call this Curtain slider. What's the proper name for this component?

[image]
https://electrek.co/2020/08/14/tesla-cybertruck-electric-pickup-working-replica-inside-out/

Comment: I have no idea how is this a duplicate question. The original one has no accepted answer, this one does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually known as "before after image slider" (just do a search on Google and you'll find a lot of results for this), maybe because before-after.js is the [basic library](http://codepen.io/bamf/pen/jEpxOX) all these scripts use.

But some people call it Juxtapose because of one of themost common [JS plugins](https://juxtapose.knightlab.com/) used to achieve this effect

Comment: You are right. Thank you.

I remember seeing these around 2010, not so often in recent years. 

This feature/function is still quite useful in certain use cases.